# Clicking 3 or 4 items reveals a button

Tags: jquery, selection

I'm working on a training module and would like to detect if the user clicks on "item 1", "item 2", and "item 3" (does not matter the order). When all the items are clicked at least once,  a button is revealed to "continue" which would take user to the next part of the training (hyperlink).  Is there a way to do this with jQuery?

Comment: what did you try??

Comment: Is it a multiselect box?

Comment: You'd probably have to do something related to Ajax and cookies...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using a multiselectbox:

```
$('option', '#selectbox').click(function() {
  if($('option:selected', '#selectbox').length >= 3) 
    $('#button').show();
});
```

Basically just use the `length` property to define the amount of elements.

Comment: +1 for both selector and context given

Answer (score 2):

You could add a class to the clicked elements with a click event handler and then count the occurrences of the class on the page.

```
$('.clickable').on('click', function(){ // item1, item2 etc
    $(this).addClass('clicked'); // CLASS TO COUNT
    if($('.clicked').length == 3) { // IF 3 HAVE CLASS
        // SHOW BUTTON
    }
});
```

`.length` returns the number items in an array (native javascript) and since `$('.selector')` returns an array of elements on the page, however many matches the selector given to `$()` (clicked class) it will have the number of occurrences on the page.